# Grunt Livereload to reload just the styles

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs, less, livereload

Added "grunt-contrib-livereload": "^0.1.2" to sass compile grunt config. Yes, it's reloading, but the whole DOM. Magento 2 native config reloader reloading just the styles, not page reload. How I can setup grunt in this way?

Thanks

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    const sass = require('node-sass');
    const timer = require('grunt-timer');

    require('time-grunt')(grunt);
    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

    timer.init(grunt, { deferLogs: true, friendlyTime: false, color: "blue" });

    grunt.initConfig({

        notify_hooks: {
            options: {
                enable: true,
                title: 'Task Completed',
                max_jshint_notifications: 5,
            },
            uncss: {
                options: {
                    title: 'Task Completeddd',
                    message: "Error occured",
                },
            },
        },

        sass: {   
            dist: {
                options: {                         
                    implementation: sass,
                    sourceMap: true,
                    message: "Less task complete"
                },
                files: {      
                    '../../../../../pub/static/frontend/Laf/v1/en_US/css/quickview.css': 'styles/quickview.scss',
                    '../../../../../pub/static/frontend/Laf/v1/en_US/css/locations.css': 'styles/locations.scss',
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            files: ['styles/*.scss', 'Magento_Cms/styles/*.scss'],
            tasks: ['sass'],
            options: {
                livereload: true,
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-notify');
    grunt.task.run('notify_hooks');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass', 'notify', 'livereload']);
};
```

Comment: You can use https://live-reload-browser-page.com . Plugin coming soon in a few days

Comment: https://github.com/Yuriy-Svetlov/live-reload-bp/blob/main/documentation/examples/gulp/README.md